# "Illegal instruction" when running ARM code targeting my CPU

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I'm compiling a rather large project for ARM. I'm using an AT91SAM9G25-EK as a devboard running a Debian ARM image. All libraries and executables in the image seem to be compiled for the armv4t instruction set.

My CPU is an ARM926EJ-S, which should run armv5tej code.

I'm using GCC to cross compile for my board. My CXX flags look like the following:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--signed-char --sysroot=${SYSROOT} -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mtune=arm926ej-s -mfloat-abi=softfp" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)`

If I try to run this on my board, I get an Illegal Instruction signal (`SIGILL`) during initialization of one of my dependencies (using armv4t).

If I enable thumb mode (`-mthumb -mthumb-interwork`) it works, but uses Thumb for all the code, which in my case runs slower (I'm doing some serious number crunching).

In this case, if I specify one function to be compiled for ARM mode (using `__attribute__((target("arm")))`) it will run fine until that function is called, then exit with `SIGILL`.

I'm lost. Is it that bad I'm linking against libraries using armv4t? Am I misunderstanding the way ARM modes work? Is it something in the linux kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `softfp` means is to use using the soft-float calling convention between functions, but still use the hardware FPU within them. Assuming your cross-compiler is configured with a default `-mfpu` option other than "none" (run `arm-whatever-gcc -v` and look for `--with-fpu=` to check), then you've got a problem, because as far as I can see from the Atmel datasheet, SAM9G25 doesn't have an FPU.

My first instinct would be to slap GDB on there, catch the signal and disassemble the offending instruction to make sure, but the fact that Thumb code works OK is already a giveaway (Thumb before ARMv6T2 doesn't include any coprocessor instructions, and thus can't make use of an FPU).

In short, use `-mfloat-abi=soft` to ensure the ARM code actually uses software floating-point and avoids poking a non-existent FPU. And if the "serious number crunching" involves a lot of floating-point, perhaps consider getting a different MCU...

Comment: You, sir, saved me a lot of struggle. I've had a stroke of bad luck with this one. I've hit a CMake bug that ignored my CXX flags from the toolchain file, prompting my compiler to default to "soft" float and "armv4t". When I discovered and fixed this, it started throwing SIGILL, prompting me to believe it's from the instruction set or linkage. One question: doesn't Thumb support hard float? Because when compiling in Thumb all was running well.

Comment: As I mentioned, Thumb hard-float can only happen from ARMv6T2 (which to all intents and purposes effectively means ARMv7) onwards, because the VFP instructions need 32-bit Thumb-2 encodings - there's simply no reasonable way to fit them into 16 bits. Because your code is still using the soft-float ABI, the compiler is free to quietly fall back to pure software FP - for comparison, try `-mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -mcpu=arm926ej-s` and see what happens then.

Comment: When I read the first part of your answer I was so stupefied by my ignorance and just had to check that was the issue. As a result, I failed to follow the whole comment. Again, thank you for the help!